# Android app crahes while using list level drawable

Tags: android, android-drawable

I want to spin the image in `imageview` as a 3d image. So i add 50 images in `imageview` by using list level `drawable`. when i add 50 images in `images.xml` the app crashes, but if i add 12 images its perfectly work. I didn't know why this error happen. I didn't find any solution yet. help me to get out from this problem.

**images.xml**

```
<level-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:maxLevel="0" android:drawable="@drawable/one"/>
    <item android:maxLevel="1" android:drawable="@drawable/two"/>
    .
    .
    .
    <item android:maxLevel="50" android:drawable="@drawable/fifty"/>
</level-list>
```

**activity.xml**

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="170dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/mid"
    android:paddingTop="40dp"
    android:id="@+id/car_icon"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/images"
    />
```

**Activity.java**

```
        imageView =  findViewById(R.id.car_icon);
        imageView.setImageLevel(x);

        "x varies depends on onTouchEvent from (0 to 50)"
```

**Error Log**

> 2019-03-04 11:02:39.207 8052-8052/revoh.innovations.smap E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: revoh.innovations.smap, PID: 8052
>       java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 12316512 byte allocation with 3972568 free bytes and 3MB until OOM
>           at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
>           at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
>           at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:620)
>           at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:455)
>           at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1155)
>           at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:720)
>           at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:571)
>           at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:771)
>           at android.graphics.drawable.LevelListDrawable.inflateChildElements(LevelListDrawable.java:134)
>           at android.graphics.drawable.LevelListDrawable.inflate(LevelListDrawable.java:93)
>           at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater.inflateFromXml(DrawableInflater.java:130)
>           at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:1227)
>           at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:1200)
>           at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:715)
>           at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:571)
>           at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:771)
>           at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:525)
>           at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:463)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:203)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:191)
>           at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:102)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatImageHelper.java:59)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.(AppCompatImageView.java:78)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.(AppCompatImageView.java:68)
>           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createImageView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:182)
>           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:106)
>           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1266)
>           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1316)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:769)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
>           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
>           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
>           at revoh.innovations.smap.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:32)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>   2019-03-04 11:02:39.207 8052-8052/revoh.innovations.smap E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)

Comment: Where is the error ? Add it with question.

Comment: @Bala, Show the crash logs

Comment: Ok i add my crash logs

Comment: Loading 50 images is required too much memory and it is crashing because of that... try reducing the image size or, load less no of images.

Comment: @Bala, your device heap size too low and you are loading high-resolution images. You will have to reduce the size

Comment: thk u @Rakesh Kumar  and digiwizkid. can i know how much the maximum size will be

Comment: @Bala, https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes and also go through support different pixel on the next page

Comment: thk u @Rakesh Kumar I solved it by reducing the load size.

Comment: @Bala, Welcome and happy to help you. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are loading way too many high resolution images at a time. [Android Training docs](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics) suggest that you scale the image before showing it on the UI. As a personal preference I rely on libraries such as [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) or [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso) to efficiently show images in an `ImageView` because whether your Image will hit the memory limit or not is based on the device and there are a lot of devices with a lot many requirements. These libraries save you from that headache.

Comment: thk u @Shababb Karim